# VS code live server extension doesn't work

Tags: html, web

When I am trying to open an HTML file with live server in VS code it

doesn't work and show me an error page

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
```

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You see the Live Server extension uses 5500 as a port, usually when such extensions are installed you need to restart VS code, have you tried to do that? Maybe restarting your entire machine would solve the problem, but anyway, have you tried to go to https://localhost:5500?

EDIT:

Set the browser for Live Server

It's possible that the extension is working, but your system doesn't have a default browser.

Even if you did set the default browser for your system, it wouldn't hurt to let Live Server know which browser you'd like to use explicitly.

First, open the Command Pallete with F1, then type in Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) and select that option.

This will open your VSCode settings.json file.

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the file, add a comma after the last setting, then paste in "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"

Comment: I've tried restarting VS code I even uninstalled it and installed it again, I tried to add the extension to the browser but it didn't work too, and I tried to go to  https://localhost:5500, and didn't work either, it was just showing me that the site can't provide a secure connection

Comment: I have updated my answer, and sorry for not using mark up, but I'm currently on my phone :)

Comment: I've tried this method before and didn't work either, I checked the default browser and checked if the live server extension default browser is the same and I tried to add live server extension and set it up on google chrome .

But I was working with the live server before and it was working good I don't know what have changed .